# jQuery selector for parent with a direct descendant

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to write a jQuery selector (it *has* to be a selector) that will select all `parent` elements that contain a specific `child` that is a direct descendant? This is equivalent to this xpath: `parent[child]`

I've already tried the following:

```
$("parent > child")
```

Doesn't work. It selects the child elements instead of the parent elements.

```
$("component > selector").parent()
```

Doesn't work. I need functionality to be contained completely within the selector. I need the selector to work when looking at both ancestors (e.g. `closest()`) and descendants (`find()`).

```
$("component:has(section)")
```

Doesn't work. It selects extra parent elements that have the child as a deeper descendant.

This is similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447525), but I need the answer to be a selector.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot select the parent of a child with pure CSS selectors.  The closest thing to it (that I know of) using JQuery is `$('childSelector').closest('parent');`  (https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in using the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), but you need to specify you're only looking for direct children.

```
$("component:has(> section)")
```

Based on this answer: [Selecting an element which has another element as direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243369/selecting-an-element-which-has-another-element-as-direct-child). Note that this isn't a pure CSS selector, but a selector specific to jQuery.